# Flutter not using build number from pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, info.plist

When I run `flutter build run` I expect the version and build number to user my version in pubspec.yaml 1.1.5+10

However the 10 is always reverting to 1.  This is set correctly in info.plist

```
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
```

But when I open xcode v12.2 it's changing `$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)` back to

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```

Somehow xcode itself is reverting these changes in info.plist.[image]

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Answer (score 26):

It's a problem in the ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file
I solved with this
[update my version and build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922857/how-to-force-flutter-to-update-my-version-and-build-number/67080868#67080868)

> change this:
>
> > `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = your buildnumber` 
> >  `MARKETING_VERSION = your version`
>
> to:
>
> > `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)";`
> > `MARKETING_VERSION = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)";`

Comment: worth noting that `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` and `MARKETING_VERSION` exist 3 times in the file, not just once

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered similar problem multiple times. What I did was set Generated configuration for all profiles [PROFILE] (Debug, Release, Profile).

Go to XCode -> Runner -> Project (Runner) -> Info.

On Target level all Runners were using Pods-Runner.[PROFILE].
On Project level there was no configuration used, so I selected Generated for all.

[image]

I don't know what are the actual implications of this change, but build version and name are picked up from Generated.xcconfig file now.

Answer (score 4):

The information in Xcode will not update just because you update and save *pubspc.yaml*. You must rebuild for iOS in order for the changes to be reflected in Xcode.

Comment: Rebuild means running “flutter build iOS” ? 

Need more detailed steps.

Comment: this should be the right answer. Yes its "flutter build ios"

Answer (score 3):

This is because Flutter build/run CLI overwrites iOS/Android build version from `pubspec.yaml`.

In my case, I use manually build(gym command of fastlane) and build version was same as before.

Use `flutter build` for build or you have to manually overwrite the version.

Comment: Running `flutter build ios` is required. Otherwise you have to: 1. Manually edit `Info-Debug.plist` and `Info-Release.plist` and update those keys/rows (`FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME` & `FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER` respectively). 2. Then manually change version and build number from your Target -> General tab -> Identity section -> "Version" and "Build"

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to go to the file located at this address:

```
./ios/runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Once opened the file had the following value defined:

```
FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER = 5
```

I replaced it with this:

```
FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)";
```

I got the version number working in the app using flavors.