# Missing BuildName and BuildNumber when building iOS bundle on flutter

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, flutter

I'm trying to build an iOS bundle for my flutter app. However the bundle doesn't get a BuildName and BuildNumber despite my best efforts.

I tried solutions from official docs, [Flutter not using build number from pubspec.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277520/flutter-not-using-build-number-from-pubspec-yaml/67108518#67108518) and [How to set build and version number of Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357468/how-to-set-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app) involving Info.plist and project.pbxproj files.

Here's the output even after specifying build name and number in commandline arguments?

```
% flutter build ipa  --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./debug-info --build-name "1.0.0" --build-number 6

Archiving com.____________.app...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: __________
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        21.1s
Xcode archive done.                                         266.8s
Built /Users/__/development/__/__/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.

[!] App Settings Validation
    ! Version Number: Missing
    ! Build Number: Missing
    • Display Name: __
    • Deployment Target: 13.0
    • Bundle Identifier: __
    ! You must set up the missing app settings.

To update the settings, please refer to https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios
```

What else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to open Xcode, open Runner > Project > Runner > Info > Configurations and set the value against release > Runner to Generated.