# iTMSTransporter could not generate an itmsp: null

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

When trying to upload my iOS app to the app store I see this error with iTMSTransporter. This occurs when using `xcrun altool` or `fastlane pilot builds` :

> 2022-04-22T01:20:31.9952870Z An exception has occurred: null
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.0055430Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1260390Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1360210Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1463160Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1563930Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1596110Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1660320Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1725320Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]    at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1770950Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1804250Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]    at
> com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.start(Application.java:450)
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1840080Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1884420Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]    at
> com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:947)
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.1987130Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.2087410Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]  2022-04-22T01:20:32.2189840Z [0m
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.2290160Z [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.2392840Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.2494790Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]   2022-04-22T01:20:32.2597270Z [0m
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.2699930Z [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.2802450Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.2903000Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter] Error Summary
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3004120Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3105710Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]   2022-04-22T01:20:32.3158440Z [0m
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3209430Z [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]
> iTMSTransporter could not generate an itmsp: null
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3259380Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3361780Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter]     An exception has occurred: null
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3461800Z [0m 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3552070Z
> [01:20:32]: [33m[iTMSTransporter] [2022-04-22 01:20:31 UTC] 
> DBG-X: Returning 1 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3611160Z [0m
> 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3668780Z [01:20:32]: iTunes Transporter output
> above ^ 2022-04-22T01:20:32.3705330Z [01:20:32]: [31miTMSTransporter
> could not generate an itmsp: null

Answer (score 3):

Although the above error is pretty ambiguous it could be a result of the actuall .ipa not being validate. This should be the first thing that is tried before diagnosing certificates etc. Use the following commands to validate your app:

```
xcrun altool --validate-app -f [ipaname].ipa --type ios -u appstore-username -p appspecific-password
```

or with app store connect api key

```
xcrun altool --validate-app -t ios --apiKey unique-api-key --apiIssuer api-key-issuer -f ipname.ipa
```

Example error output

```
2022-04-26 09:09:22.285 *** Error: The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key. Unable to validate your application. (-27001)  {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Unable to validate your application."; }
```

Comment: may be someone help this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922857/how-to-force-flutter-to-update-my-version-and-build-number

Comment: woah what a great answer thanks a lot! The errors given from the pipeline sure be really meaningful.